# Xamarin.Forms AppCompat MasterDetail no titlebar showing

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms, android-appcompat

I have a problem with Xamarin.Forms (v2.3)

I followed this guide:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/android/appcompat/

And so far I have been able to integrate the Material design successfully in my Forms app.

What is not actually working as I would love to is the MasterDetail, that I am calling from a LoginPage with this line:

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new HomePage());
```

What is not working can be seen in these screenshots:

[image]

[image]

The MasterDetail appers, but the title bar with the title and the hamburger logo do not.
This is the code that describes my MasterDetail:

```
<MasterDetailPage
  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  x:Class="MyClassPath"
  Title="Care Page">

  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Title">
      <Label/>
    </ContentPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>

  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <ContentPage Title="Title">
      <Label/>
    </ContentPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>

 </MasterDetailPage>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a NavigationPage to show the title and icon, so you can set your detail as a NavigationPage.

For example :

```
Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage { Title = "Title" });
```

Comment: I already tried this: await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new HomePage())); which leads me to have a double (!) bar, with a backarrow that if pressed shuts down the app and still doesn't show the hamburger icon: http://imgur.com/a/OZyx0 Is what I tried similar to what you suggested me to do or I can still fix it? :) Thanks

Comment: I was able to solve it exactly as you mentioned :) I am not sure why it didn't work earlier!